# "Too Broad" Flag Declined on Video Encoding Question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags

I was browsing the [youtube-livestreaming-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-livestreaming-api) tag and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31868265/2415822) about broadcasting live to YouTube in a Windows 10 app.  Because this question is basically asking "how do I write a video encoder for a Windows 10 app," I flagged it as too broad.  The flag was declined.

Was I wrong to flag this question?  How can anyone provide a succinct answer to such an open question about video encoding?  I feel as if it's basically a tool suggestion question in disguise.

This question is also a breeding ground for link-only answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31938420/2415822)), which is why I believe the question should be closed in the first place.

Figured I'd start a discussion here to see what other users thought about the quality of question.

Comment: The review that declined the flag: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9310657

Comment: @BradLarson thanks, good find.

Comment: Gone now. Maybe it will be reopened, but I for one agree with you.

Comment: As an aside, you're pretty close to 3k rep. You should try to finish it off so you can put actual close votes on things instead of just flags.

Comment: @durron597 Thanks, you made that suggestion to me a few months ago on chat and I've been working on it since :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can't speak for the other reviewers but I think you flagged that question correctly as being too broad.

The answers are high-level hints, links to documentation and tool recommendations, the question lacks a clear statement of which code doesn't work, if there is code at all.

I've casted a close vote on that question so it is fresh in the close vote queue now. There is nothing wrong with your judgment.

Let's see how this one ends...

<sup>It ended up as closed for being too broad</sup>